# driver.Close is not closing browser in Selenium3

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium3

I am trying to close browser using `driver.close()` in Selenium3. But it's not working. Please help me with that

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\Phani\\Tools\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
        wd.get("https://google.com");
        try{
        wd.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
            //System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());

        }
    }

}
```

I'm getting following error during close().

```
---------------------------------------------
Failed to interpret value as array
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'PCNAME-PC', ip: '192.168.0.105', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, appBuildId=20160623154057, version=47.0.1, platform=XP, proxy=Proxy(), command_id=1.0, specificationLevel=0.0, acceptSslCerts=false, browserVersion=47.0.1, platformVersion=6.1, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=Firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Windows_NT, device=desktop}]
Session ID: b5fa76b7-80b1-49d1-806e-cee7032259ef
---------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you performing any other tests in your code, so instead of close() can you use `wd.quit();`

Comment: Quit is working , But I am clueless why Close is not working .... Any reason why wd.close() is not working. Could it be any browser issue ? or version mis-match ??

Comment: @Phani `close()` is used to close the browser only but the driver instance still remains dangling. To avoid this situation we need to use `quit()` to close the driver instance as well. Do let me know if this answers your question. Thanks.

Comment: @bad_deadpool Honestly I am yet to analyze the `close()` in Selenium 3.4.0 for Mozilla Firefox. Interestingly​ geckodriver have addressed the crash issue on `quit()` in v0.16.0 release.

Comment: You will get your answer here - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/blob/master/src/marionette.rs

Comment: @bad_deadpool `wd.close()` should perfectly work with geckodriver v0.16.1 - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3922

Comment: @Phani can you confirm which version of geckodriver you are using? Thanks

Comment: @Dev  I am using "0.16.0 " version geckodriver.

Comment: @Phani @Phani Refer to my previous comment, geckodriver v0.16.1 will address your `wd.close()` issue. Let me know if this answers your question. Thanks